# Select records with maximum value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table that is called: `customers`.

I'm trying to get the name and the salary of the people who have the maximum salary.

So I have tried this:

```
SELECT name, salary AS MaxSalary
FROM CUSTOMERS 
GROUP BY salary
HAVING salary = max(salary)
```

Unfortunately, I got this error:

> Column 'CUSTOMERS.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I know I should add the name column to the `group by` clause, but I get all the records of the table.

I know that I can do it by:

```
SELECT name, salary
FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE salary = (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM CUSTOMERS)
```

But I want to achieve it by `group by` and `having` clauses.

Answer (score 3):

This requirement isn't really suited for a `group by` and `having` solution. The easiest way to do so, assuming you're using a modern-insh version of MS SQL Server, is to use the [`rank`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) window function:

```
SELECT name, salary
FROM   (SELECT name, salary, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) rk
        FROM   customers) c
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Mureinik's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35241132/3183588) is good with rank, but if you didn't want a windowed function for whatever reason, you can just use a [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) or a subquery.

```
with mxs as (
  select
    max(salary) max_salary
  from
    customers
)
select
  name
  ,salary
from
  customers cst
  join mxs on mxs.max_salary = cst.salary
```

Answer (score -1):

There was no need to use group by and having clause there, you know. But if you want to use them then query should be

```
SELECT name, salary 
FROM CUSTOMERS 
GROUP BY salary 
having salary = (select max(salary) from CUSTOMERS)
```

Comment: This is just a more complicated version of the OP's query, which doesn't work, too.

Comment: Of course this query works. 
 what  error do you get?

Comment: You'll get: "*Column 'CUSTOMERS.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*"

Comment: it works in the following environment.
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.5.40 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: The question is tagged `SQL Server` not `mysql`. MySQL has some 'uncommon'  extensions, all other DBMSes will return an error message.